# Included libraries still cause "undefined reference" error

Tags: c++, eclipse, gcc

I have installed this http://www.sfml-dev.org/index.php library on my Ubuntu system. The files are stored in /usr/local/include.

My Eclipse DOES include these files under "Includes >> GNU C++" but if I build the program, the compiler complains about undefined references.

```
#include <SFML/System.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  sf::Clock Clock;
  return 0;
}
```

Causes:

```
undefined reference to `sf::Clock::Clock()' main.cpp
```

Any guess what I missed to do?

Comment: forget to add library to link dependency?

Comment: Oh no, sorry. It is C++ header-only stuff.

Comment: Any other ideas? I still can't run it..

Comment: AFAIC you're doing all correct. Can you add final GCC compilation string to problem description, if your IDE accepts such output?

Comment: I think I know whats wrong, look at my answer. Just add -lsfml-system to get all stuff working.

Comment: You are right. I got another problem.. I needed to call "sudo ldconfig" after that I was able to compile and run the program. So now I am trying to tell eclipse to do that too and use -lsfml-system for his g++ invokation..

Comment: "C/C++ Build" -> "Settings" and then hit the "Libraries" item under "GCC C++ Linker" heading in the list on the right. Then, enter the libraries as you would in the command line ("pthread" for libpthread, etc...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was right in my first suggestion.

[Here](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/1.6/start-linux.php) documented, that you must compile like:

```
g++ -c clock.cpp
g++ -o clock clock.o -lsfml-system
```

So please add -lsfml-system to libraries.

Comment: Thank you, you were right.. but I needed to call "sudo ldconfig" first. Didn't know that..

Answer (score 0):

According to the [SFML tutorial](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/1.6/start-linux.php), you need to link to the libraries with "-l" directive. So, make sure eclipse did that on your behalf and try to override the flags if it didn't.

Comment: Disagree. Then it must be "can not find include file" problem

Comment: I don't use Eclipse so I'm not sure what kinds of errors it may give.

Comment: As mentioned above.. it now works if I do it manually. The only thing left is to tell Eclipse how to compile it correctly.. ^